# Symfony toolbar

Tags: symfony, curl, migration, toolbar

after upgrading from Symfony version 6.3 to 6.4, I'm receiving this PHP message: [debug] Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelTerminate". It's not a problem as it disappears in production, but the issue is that this message gets appended to the end of my cURL calls, thus preventing their execution. I want to keep my toolbar and not have to switch my debug mode to false. Thank you for your responses.

In resume that looke like = json_encode(cURL call).PHP_message;

Without debugg (in prod) PHP_message is dropped out and the encoded JSON is correctly sent.

```
    $options = [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $bearer,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ],
        $param => $aData,
    ];

    return $this->client->request($requete, self::URL . $where, $options);
```

Just a simple request...
I would can be able to use the toolbar even with curl call

Comment: I don't understand your question. This is just a debug notice so shouldn't prevent anything.

Comment: I quite agree but the message kernel terminate go to the end of the curl call, i don't understand more, the end of the curl call :  },
        "NbCli": 4,
        "NbCliMax": 100
    }
}PHP message: [
    debug
]Notified event "kernel.terminate"to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelTerminate".

Comment: Please share some relevant code, so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: Well, i don't know what i could show, all worked neatly on version 6.2 and 6.3,  tested by Unity Test. May be my yaml (sorry for the delay had a very hard day yesterday), when@dev:
    web_profiler:
        toolbar: true
        intercept_redirects: false

    framework:
        profiler:
            only_exceptions: false
            collect_serializer_data: true

when@test:
    web_profiler:
        toolbar: false
        intercept_redirects: false

    framework:
        profiler: { collect: false }

Comment: Please update your question with additional information , instead of commenting. And please share some information about your cURL calls, that part is not clear to me. And it's working fine without debug?